# Can't use Medium Editor addElements(elements)

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I would like to add some html to my page using [Medium Editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#addelementselements) addElements() function. I don't really know how to use it. For now it just adds an editable blank line...

My code:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.changeable');
elements = "<section id='"+new_id+"' class='changeable'><h1 class='title_section'>"+newTitle+"</h1><p>This is a new paragraph.</p></section>";
editor.addElements(".container_content",elements);
```

My selector is the element with a "container_content" class. I would like to add the html of the var "elements" in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.
You have to create your element you want to add first. Then you call .addElements(yourElement)